# Calling arbitrary k8s apis using the Python client

Tags: python, authentication, kubernetes, openshift

I'd like to call the openshift machine api (`/apis/machine.openshift.io/v1beta1/machines`). Is there a way to do this using the `kubernetes` Python module?  I can create an api object like this:

```
>>> from kubernetes import client, config
>>> config.load_incluster_config()
>>> api = client.CoreV1API()
```

Of course, that's a core API client, which doesn't include native support for the `machine` api. But the object has all the endpoint and authentication information. There is a likely looking `api.api_client.call_api` method, but it doesn't seem to make use of the auth information embedded in the api_client object:

```
>>> api.api_client.call_api('/apis/machine.openshift.io/v1beta1/machines', 'GET')
[...]
kubernetes.client.rest.ApiException: (403)
Reason: Forbidden
```

I can explicitly pass in auth information, but then it doesn't seem to return any content:

```
>>> >>> api.api_client.call_api('/apis/machine.openshift.io/v1beta1/machines', 'GET', auth_settings=api.api_client.configuration.auth_settings())
(None, 200, HTTPHeaderDict({'Audit-Id': '6f6965b5-1ad7-4c5e-ab61-343e38718ff8', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, private', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-Kubernetes-Pf-Flowschema-Uid': '9
5848e47-b51c-46eb-aa4f-e25130d61e09', 'X-Kubernetes-Pf-Prioritylevel-Uid': '39391d77-7b32-4aa2-93c3-9915a302d361', 'Date': 'Fri, 04 Sep 2020 19:43:59 GMT', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'}))
```

I can of course just use `requests`:

```
>>> requests.get(f'{api.api_client.configuration.host}/apis/machine.openshift.io/v1beta1/machines', verify=False, headers=api.api_client.configuration.api_key)
<Response [200]>
```

That works fine, but it smells like I'm going about things the wrong way. What's the correct way to make arbitrary API requests using the Python `kubernetes` module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring from [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/issues/528) you could use `api_client.call_api` as below to call arbitrary APIs by passing a valid `BearerToken` which could be a service account token.

```
api_client.call_api('/apis/machine.openshift.io/v1beta1/machines', 'GET', auth_settings = ['BearerToken'], response_type='json', _preload_content=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. The question is really about calling arbitrary APIs, including those not in the `CoreV1API`. I'll update it with a different example.

Comment: Oh, that's prefect! I had been reading through that same github issue but I missed some of the details. Thanks!